# Different way to render an icon REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sonarqube

I have that error in SonarQube: Remove the declaration of the unused 'Ico' variable.

And thats my code:

```
const ReactPage = (props) => {
    const {nomeCLasse} = props
    const icon = {};
     icon[opcaoAvaliacao.Satisfeito] = InsertEmoticonRoundedIcon;
     icon[opcaoAvaliacao.Neutro] = SentimentSatisfiedRoundedIcon;
    
     const render = () => {
        const Ico = icon[nomeClasse];
        return <Ico className={`iconeDescricao${nomeClasse}`} />;
      };
}
```

When I render this way the sonar gives me an error on line 5(const Ico = icon[nomeClasse]).

How do I render an icon in a different way than this with this icon dictionary?

Comment: You are declaring an object called `icon`. Try doing `const Ico = icon.nomeClasse` instead of `const Ico = icon[nomeClasse]`

Comment: It looks like SonarQube doesn't see that the variable is actually used as a component just below. And it looks like they were notified of this [bug](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/1951) and fixed it for version 8.5 and up.